# Use the previous value if condition is met in R while using ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement

I came across an issue while converting one of if.. else condition to ifelse () in R to make the process faster. In this question, I have to use the value from the previous row if the condition is met. I was not able to replicate the same results from my code Below is the if.. else statement and its converted code.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(newdata)){


    if ((newdata$first == 1)){
      newdata[, decvar][i] = groups + 1 - ceiling(round((newdata$cum/total) * groups, 4))
    } #calculate decile; if var = 0, decile = 0
    else if (newdata$first == 0){
      newdata[, decvar][i] = newdata[, decvar][i-1]
    }
  }
```

Using ifelse():

```
brv_trx1$decvar <- ifelse(((brv_trx1$first == 1)),(11 - ceiling(round((brv_trx1$cum/total) * 10, 4))),
                          ifelse(((brv_trx1$first == 0)), lag(brv_trx1$decvar) ,NA))
```

The sample output will look something like this :

```
variable   First  Decvar 

45          1      10

42          1      10

31          1       9

30          0       9

30          0       9

29          0       8

29          0       8

28          0       8

21          1       7
```

I was getting some output as 0, which I have no clue where it came from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here might be in brv_trx1 that you have a vector of lags as an output, see here:

```
a<-c(0,1,0)
> ifelse(a==0,1,0)
[1] 1 0 1
> ifelse(a==0,a,0)
[1] 0 0 0
```

The condition does what it is supposed to in the first one (overwrites a zero with a one). In the second case we have a vector so if a is zero, like it is in the last value the vector just goes to the same point in a, thus you have a zero. Since you are conditioning on zero, you get zeros.

Solution:

```
ifelse(a==0,c(2,1,2),0)
[1] 2 0 2
```

I would create the same lag vector and pad an NA at the end, so:

```
c(brv_trx1$decvar[-1],NA) instead of the lag(brv_trx1$decvar)
```